# How do i iterate over alternate elements(or taking leaps of specific size) in set?

Tags: c++, set

In other words, what I mean to say is : **Is itr+=2 a valid argument in c++ ?**, where (itr is an iterator to first element of the set). If so, then the following piece of code should work:
In this piece if code, the code written in **/*comment section*/** functions well, while the code not in comment section do not. **Help me out to iterate alternate elements.**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  set<int> s;
  s.insert(5);
  s.insert(7);
  s.insert(8);
  auto it=s.begin();
  cout<<*it<<'\n';
  it+=2;
  cout<<*it<<'\n';
  /*for(auto it=s.begin();it!=s.end();it++)
    cout<<*it<<" ";*/
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: With range-v3: `for (auto e : s | ranges::views::stride(2)) {std::cout << e << std::endl; }`

Comment: `std::advance(it, 2);` as `std::set::iterator` are not random access iterator.

Comment: Not directly related, but see those questions as well: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is itr+=2 a valid argument in c++?

It depends on the container type. For example, it would be perfectly valid for `std::vector` or `std::array`, but not for `std::set`. Each container, due to its nature, provides different types of iterators. `std::set` only provides [BidirectionalIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator), which do not support jumping over arbitrary number of elements, only incrementation and decrementation.

However, you can use [`std::advance()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) from `<iterator>` library (or just increment the iterator twice). Beware that you must never increment `end()` iterator, so you need to take it into account in loop condition.

```
for(auto it=s.begin(); it != s.end() && it != std::prev(s.end()); std::advance(it, 2))
```

Comment: I would not use `std::prev` as the condition is never met for containers with an even number of elements. Also `std::advance` changes the iterator in place and doesn't return anything.
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cTHaua

Comment: Re: "It depends on the container type" -- that's correct as far as it goes, but the true rule is that it depends on the **iterator** type. A pair of iterators designates a sequence of values. Containers are one way of managing sequences, but they are not the only way. For example, `std::istream_iterator` extracts elements from an `std::istream` object, which is not (except by an extremely forced definition) a container. +1.